# Prevent scrolling outside map area on google map

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Am actually dealing with the Google Maps Framework for iOS, and I want to block scrolling out side a giving area.

What I tried to do at first, implement the delegate method : `- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position` and compare the map position with the right/left corners.But what I did has many issues when scrolling or zooming.

Below an exemple of my implementation :

```
 - (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didChangeCameraPosition:(GMSCameraPosition *)position {  

    if (position.target.latitude > topLat) { 
        GMSCameraPosition *goBackCamera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:topLat
                                                                      longitude:position.target.longitude
                                                                            zoom:position.zoom
                                                                            bearing:220
                                                                            viewingAngle:0];

        [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:goBackCamera];
    }

    if (position.target.latitude < bottomLat) {
        GMSCameraPosition *goBackCamera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:bottomLat
                                                                      longitude:position.target.longitude
                                                                           zoom:position.zoom
                                                                        bearing:220
                                                                   viewingAngle:0];
        [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:goBackCamera];
    }

    if (position.target.longitude > rightLong) {
        GMSCameraPosition *goBackCamera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:position.target.latitude
                                                                      longitude:rightLong
                                                                           zoom:position.zoom
                                                                        bearing:220
                                                                   viewingAngle:0];
        [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:goBackCamera];
    }

    if (position.target.longitude < leftLong) {
        GMSCameraPosition *goBackCamera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:position.target.latitude
                                                                      longitude:leftLong
                                                                           zoom:position.zoom
                                                                        bearing:220
                                                                   viewingAngle:0];
        [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:goBackCamera];
    }
}
```

Do you no a way more efficient to deal with this?

PS: TopLat, RightLong ... mean top Latitude and Right longitude etc

Regards

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think of is by setting up the bound in the map in you want maps to scroll using [GMSCoordinateBounds](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds#a63cffdf310ca19c6bab74c9a4034aadd).

Next thing you can do is to set up the [scroll gesture](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#a2d9e62a5b4d7d9d5c60760f0a2566059) to true just within that section of maps you have specified above bounds. For the rest of the map the scroll gesture should be false.

Answer (score 0):

Use GMSCoordinateBounds(northeast co-ordinates, southwest co-ordinates) method.
This might be helpful
[GMSCoordinateBounds Class Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_coordinate_bounds)

Comment: Let me know if need any further help